# WPF usercontrol shows configuration error

Tags: wpf

I have a simple UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="UIWpf.UserControls.MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="149*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="149*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="151*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBoxVersions" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock >Tests to be run for:</TextBlock>
            <ComboBox  Name="ComboBoxFileTypeSelector" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedIndex="0">
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, I am using this UserControl in the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="UIWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns:u="clr-namespace:UIWpf.UserControls"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition>
      </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <u:MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl x:Name="MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl"></u:MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl>
         </Grid>
</Window>
```

The UserControl uses data binding and data comes from a source which is configured in the config file.

I have the configuration settings in the app.config and when I run the application, the MainForm works fine with the UserControl populated with the data.
But at compile time I still see an error saying , the setting is missing from the configuration file.

Comment: Have you checked the config file in the bin directory?

Comment: @GlenThomas Yes, it also has the setting.

Comment: Can you include the code that accesses the application configuration?